# Can I pass a filter value from different page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm using [jQuery Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) on a project.

Can I pass filter values to it from an a href link on a different page? So when I land on the page with the isotope, it filters the layout based on the a href.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use the [hash history addin](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/hash-history.html) for Isotope, which makes use of [jQuery BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/).

This example is just copypasta from the source of the hash history page on the Isotope docs.

```
$(window).bind( 'hashchange', function( event ){
    // get options object from hash
    var hashOptions = window.location.hash ? $.deparam.fragment( window.location.hash, true ) : {},
        // do not animate first call
        aniEngine = hashChanged ? 'best-available' : 'none',
        // apply defaults where no option was specified
        options = $.extend( {}, defaultOptions, hashOptions, { animationEngine: aniEngine } );
// apply options from hash
$container.isotope( options );
// save options
isotopeOptions = hashOptions;

// if option link was not clicked
// then we'll need to update selected links
if ( !isOptionLinkClicked ) {
  // iterate over options
  var hrefObj, hrefValue, $selectedLink;
  for ( var key in options ) {
    hrefObj = {};
    hrefObj[ key ] = options[ key ];
    // convert object into parameter string
    // i.e. { filter: '.inner-transition' } -> 'filter=.inner-transition'
    hrefValue = $.param( hrefObj );
    // get matching link
    $selectedLink = $optionSets.find('a[href="#' + hrefValue + '"]');
    changeSelectedLink( $selectedLink );
  }
}

isOptionLinkClicked = false;
hashChanged = true;
})

    // trigger hashchange to capture any hash data on init
    .trigger('hashchange');

});
```

Comment: Hi guys, can you make a example for that? Like a jsfidlle.